# How do I convert date class to parse date time correctly?

Tags: java, datetime, parsing, simpledateformat

I'm very new to Java.
I'm fetching this date `1995-01-28T17:02:12.936000-0500` from oracle db and now I want to convert it into `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` format. I have tried below method

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS");
Date c=sdf.parse("1995-01-28T17:02:12.936000-0500");
SimpleDateFormat sdf1=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

System.out.println(sdf1.format(c));
```

I'm getting below output

`1995-2-28 17:17:48`
You can see that 17:02:12 is getting changed to 17:17:48. How do I fix this ?

Comment: I plant to use that date and time as a string

Comment: `936000` ms is 15 minutes, pretty sure the difference comes from those

Comment: I'm sorry If dont get this. But does this mean the total time is correct?

Comment: I doubt it : I assume the 936000 by the end of the date you retrieve should be understood as 936 ms (and the last 3 zeroes would be for additional precision), but SimpleDateFormat doesn't have any format for anything more precise than milliseconds. See if you can change the format of the date you retrieve

Comment: @Aaron ok I get it now why the extra minutes were added onto it.

Comment: You are using terrible date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it like this.  But use the methods in the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) package.  It is superior in many ways to the `java.util.Date` and supported methods which are outmoded (and quite a few are deprecated).

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZ");
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse("1995-01-28T17:02:12.936000-0500",dtf);
DateTimeFormatter resultFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println(odt.format(resultFormat));
```

Prints

```
1995-01-28 17:02:12
```

Comment: No need for a DateTimeFormatter when parsing.  [OffsetDateTime.parse(String)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#parse(java.lang.CharSequence)) will handle that format by default.

Comment: @VGR  I tried it and it wouldn't work.  Perhaps because there is no colon in the offset of the OP's timestamp.

Comment: @VGR The input data omits the optional COLON Character between the hours and minutes of the offset. The default parser expects that missing character. So parsing fails.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the **000** from the **936000**.  The date parser treats that as 936,000 milliseconds, which is adding 936 seconds, or about 15 minutes, to your date/time.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this.